# D3: Change text in url without making request

Tags: url, select, d3.js

Suppose I have a url "http://example.com?name=FOO" on the browser, how do I change it to "http://example.com?name=BAR" without making new request, like selecting and changing title text from "FOO" to "BAR".

```
d3.select("title").text('BAR');
```

Is there way or isn't?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Javascript, D3.js not required for this. Try this:

```
window.location.search = "?name=BAR";
```

if you want to do it without refresh:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

Refer: http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

Comment: Well, I just want to change the text (appearance) but not to make a request, and then go on with current script. This way you make a new request.

Comment: Seems like a security nightmare.

Comment: Sameer Shemna, got it. Thank you very much! :) veritas, why? You don't make a request though. Right?